# Suspend and send a job to background in VIM 8

Tags: vim, xonsh

I've been trying to use VIM 8.1 with terminal support instead of tmux.
It's been going pretty well. One problem I ran into is when I run something from a terminal and I want to sent it to the background when I press Ctrl-z it just prints "^Z". How can I send Ctrl-Z to a terminal inside of vim?

Comment: On which operating system, terminal and shell? As far as I know it should work just fine unless there's something very specific preventing it (you can't suspend a bash shell prompt, for example)

Comment: Are you trying to suspend Vim while in insert mode? If so, that's not what insert mode is for - you will get `^Z` inserted into the text instead. Exit to command mode and suspend should work normally.

Comment: I was using http://xonsh.org which has trouble emulating a terminal 100% correctly. Using bash/zsh seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/issues/2353